# GROUP BY month WHERE range of dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following columns:

[image]

NETID is a unique identifier for the user, OCCURRENCES is the number of times they've logged in in a month, and EARLIEST_MONTHLY_DATE is the earliest time they logged in for a month. I've currently using:

```
SELECT 
    to_char(earliest_monthly_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') MARCH, 
    COUNT(NETID) unique_login_count
FROM 
    REPORT_SERVICE_USAGE 
WHERE 
    earliest_monthly_date >= to_date('2014-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
AND earliest_monthly_date <= to_date('2014-03-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
GROUP BY 
    to_char(earliest_monthly_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd')
ORDER BY 
    to_char(earliest_monthly_date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') ASC
```

which gives me the total number of logins per day in a given month. It returns something like this:

[image]

Now, I want to set up my query so that it groups the login count by month instead of by day of a given month. I'm not sure how to do this (or if it can be done), as I'm not very familiar with SQL, but any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need any more info, feel free to ask. By the way, it's an Oracle database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    to_char(earliest_monthly_date, 'yyyy-mm') MARCH, 
    COUNT(NETID) unique_login_count
FROM 
    REPORT_SERVICE_USAGE 
WHERE 
    earliest_monthly_date >= to_date('2014-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
AND earliest_monthly_date <= to_date('2014-03-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
GROUP BY 
    to_char(earliest_monthly_date, 'yyyy-mm')
ORDER BY 
    to_char(earliest_monthly_date, 'yyyy-mm') ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the select and group by 'to_char' to extract

```
SELECT 
    extract(MONTH from earliest_monthly_date) MARCH, 
    COUNT(NETID) unique_login_count
FROM 
    REPORT_SERVICE_USAGE 
WHERE 
    earliest_monthly_date >= to_date('2014-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
AND earliest_monthly_date <= to_date('2014-03-31', 'yyyy-mm-dd')
GROUP BY 
    extract(MONTH from earliest_monthly_date)
ORDER BY 
    extract(MONTH from earliest_monthly_date) ASC
```

**Edit**

If you like the groups to by by month and year the answer from @Lamak is a better option.

Comment: I wish I could give you both best answer, but his did order things a little better. I needed the year because the span was 2013-2014, so I needed to be able to differentiate. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @jordaniac89 no problem! I'm here just to help not to acumulate points :)